# Getting Site Matching Query Does Not Exist Error after creating django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-sites

I'm going through the standard Django tutorial to create an admin for an app. After commenting the admin related stuff in settings and running syncdb I'm getting this message:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/ Site matching query does not exist.
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The `Site` object for your Django project is missing. Each Django project has a `Site` object which contains the site's name and domain. It is usually automatically created when creating a Django project (in particular, when the `syncdb` command runs) but in your case it seems that didn't happen.

To fix it:

Open the Django shell for your site (`python manage.py shell`).

Type the following:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.create(name='example.com', domain='example.com')
```

If you want to change these values later, go to your admin panel (`/admin/`) and edit the site object in the section `Sites`.

Comment: thanks so much. just to clarify at which point in creating your site should the site object be created? When you do: django-admin.py startproject mysite?

Comment: @DavidHaddad: I just checked the Django source and it happens after the `syncdb` command has created the tables. If your project then uses the `django.contrib.sites` addon then it'll run some code to create the `Site` object.

Comment: Sweet, it's exactly after running syncdb that the error was raised. Thanks again.

Comment: Have to also change the SITE_ID in settings.py

Comment: I still got the error after I created the site object with name "example.com". Please help

Comment: As Brian mentioned [along with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737344/943773), setting `SITE_ID=1`  did the trick for me. You can also just remove `sites` from `INSTALLED_APPS` as mentioned the answer I linked.

Answer (score 45):

In addition to Simeon Visser's answer for those of you still experiencing problems, make sure the `SITE_ID` variable in your settings matches the ID of your newly created `Site`-object.

Comment: Definitely worth noting that with django 1.8, migrating after adding the `contrib.sites` does add a site, but you must add the `SITE_ID` setting. Simeon's answer isn't even required - just the `SITE_ID` to 1.

Comment: if you screw it up like I just did with deleting the record with SITE_ID 1, just create the new record with id=1 in the shell.

Comment: i spent about 30 minutes trying to debug this..turns out i had deleted the initiated site provided by default in django 'example.com' anf therefore my site id was not 1

Answer (score 37):

When you include the **django.contrib.sites** to your INSTALLED_APPS and run the command "python manage.py migrate" the app automatically creates a object into "django_site" table (with domain name and display name equals to "example.com". There is no need to create it by yourself.

Probably you just need to add the setting **SITE_ID = 1** to your settings.py file.

Answer (score 10):

If you already have example.com in your sites table after you run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

You need to get id of this entry.

To get the ID you can do -

```
python manage.py  shell
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
print Site.objects.get(name='example.com').id
```

Get the id you get here into `setting.py` . Eg.

```
SITE_ID = 8
```

Basically ID in table corresponding yo tour site and in the settings.py should match.

Answer (score 7):

comment out django.contrib.sites from the installed apps. i.e.

```
#'django.contrib.sites',
```

Comment: This fixed my issue as I had been playing with my settings trying to get a package to work.

Comment: Yup. +1. Although not necessarily a fix for people needing sites; this is very helpful for diagnosing where the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You could also consider of using fixture feature of django to populate the data automatically: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

```
[
    {
        "model" : "sites.site",
        "pk" : 1,
        "fields": {
            "name"  : "example.com",
            "domain" : "127.0.0.1:8010"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Site object is missed so you have to add 1 Site object

Solution:

open Django shell(python **manage.py** shell):

```
In [1]: from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

In [2]: Site.objects.create(name='example.com',domain='example.com').save()

In [3]: s=Site.objects.filter(name='example.com')[0]

In [4]: s.id
Out[4]: 3
```

then open your `settings.py` file and add `SITE_ID = 3`
put that value in  `SITE_ID` = which you get after (`s.id`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Django newbie. I got the same error when going through the tutorial. My `django_site` DB table was empty. I chose to drop all tables named "django_*". Then when I reran `syncdb`, the missing django tables were created, and the `django_site` DB table was populated with id=1, domain=example.com, name=example.com. Evidently the `Site` class is backed by the `django_site` DB table. Now I understand the problem and the solution above that populated the table using the `Site.objects.create()` method. Thanks Simeon.

Answer (score 0):

If you use South and initial_data fixtures, data could be loaded not properly. To fix it add

```
if 'test' in sys.argv or 'jenkins' in sys.argv:
    SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

at the end of your settings file

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you add more Sites via Admin and delete some of them each site has an ID, it was not working for me once I changed the ID in the DB it started working, so make sure SITE_ID matches the ID in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same error for quite some time now. I had by mistake deleted the example.com from sites directory in admin. Once I added the site using above solutions, it worked. Also site_id automatically became 2 when I created the example.com and so had to change site_id to 2 in my settings file also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its all due to if you accidentally delete site from django admin site which is by default (example.com). The code mentioned below also raised an Runtime error.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
```

so simply make an increment in your `SITE_ID` by `1`
For example if by default it is `1` than change it with `2`
change from 
`SITE_ID = 1`
TO:
`SITE_ID = 2`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.create(name='example.com', domain='example.com')
```

Above solved the issue.

But when I logged in Admin Panel, there was another site example.com so I believe if someone puts SITE_ID = 2 this will also work.