# Django - Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im trying to get the admin site of my app in Django working. Ive just sync`d the DB and then gone to the site but I get the error ...

```
Site matching query does not exist.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: It's a duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476210/getting-site-matching-query-does-not-exist-error-after-creating-django-admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Site Matching Query Does Not Exist Error after creating django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476210/getting-site-matching-query-does-not-exist-error-after-creating-django-admin)

Comment: I removed `example.com` site in `django_site` table and added new domain. So I had same issue with you.
I changed value of `SITE_ID` to `2` in `settings.py` file. It's for new site.
```
SITE_ID=2
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Every django app needs a `Site` to run. Here you do not seem to have it.

Log into your django shell

```
$> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site()
>>> site.domain = 'example.com'
>>> site.name = 'example.com'
>>> site.save()
```

or

```
$> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site.objects.create(domain='example.com', name='example.com')
>>> site.save()
```

You should be all set.

Comment: How would/should this be added via the settings file ?

Comment: You cannot add it via settings. do `./manage.py shell` and there execute these commands

Comment: Ok thanks I just wondered why my app didnt have this. Also what reference does the domain have within Django. Thanks again...

Comment: Also make sure you set `SITE_ID` in `settings.py` to 0.

Comment: I love this way to solve any issues with models in broken Django site...

Comment: In my case I had also to delete existing records and set id=1 like:`Site.objects.all().delete()
;Site.objects.create(id=1,domain='example.com', name='example.com').save()`
This was after loading from json and strangely id was 5

Answer (score 44):

Add `django.contrib.sites` in django `INSTALLED_APPS` and
also add `SITE_ID=1` in your django setting file.

Comment: its plural `django.contrib.sites`

Comment: SITE_ID means in the database table you create a objects where you will add site name according to your app like facebook.com. xyx.com so you can add according to your need

Comment: I was missing the `SITE_ID=1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Adding `SITE_ID=1` on settings.py did the trick for me.

Comment: Yes, here is the official proof. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but this did the trick for me!

Answer (score 9):

You also need to make sure that the site domain is the same with the one you actually use. For example if you are you are accessing the admin site from http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ then your site.domain should be: site.domain = '127.0.0.1:8000'.

Answer (score 5):

Try out this in **settings.py**:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`SITE_ID = 1` i didn't work for me

I had to go to the python shell
`./manage.py shell`

Then get the existing site id using name or domain

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.get(name='back').id
> 6
```

For me it was 6, all i had to do then is to change the `SITE_ID = 6` and it worked fine

Comment: instead of changing it in settings.py, i change it in db to 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm using wsgi, so I had **to reboot** twice, not sure why.

then clear cache and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me after deleting 'example.com' the sites from Site modal

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Sites.objects.filter(domain='example.com').delete()
```