# Django-CMS - example page deleted

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I just installed django-cms on my server. Right after the installation, there was an example site (example.com).

To adapt the site to my needs, I deleted this site. It seems like this was a mistake - now all I get "DoesNotExist"-Exceptions, even when I go to /admin/.

Is it possible to repair that or would resetting the installation be an easier solution?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068518/django-site-matching-query-does-not-exist/16068551#16068551

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but that didn't solve it. Still a "DoesNotExist"-Exceptions :(

Comment: You have to set the `SITE_ID` in your `settings.py` to the `pk` of the site object.

Comment: `Site.objects.all()[0].pk` returned `5` so I set SITE_ID to `5` Still no luck :(

Comment: sorry, needed to restart django ... now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @karthikr stated

first run

```
$> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site.objects.create(domain='example.com', name='example.com')
>>> site.save()
```

then lookup the Site-Id:

```
>>>Site.object.all()[0].pk
```

Use this value in `settings.py` for the value of `SITE_ID`

Don't forget to restart django.