# DoesNotExist at /accounts/register/ Site matching query does not exist. (django, python)

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-registration

Trying again to implement django-registration. When I try to deploy it to the heroku and to register a new user, it gives me a strange error:

```
Traceback:

#some irrelevant traceback

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in post
  43.             return self.form_valid(request, form)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py" in form_valid
  91.         new_user = self.register(request, form)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/backends/default/views.py" in register
  86.         site = get_current_site(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py" in get_current_site
  15.         return Site.objects.get_current(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
  67.             return self._get_site_by_request(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in _get_site_by_request
  44.                 SITE_CACHE[host] = self.get(domain__iexact=host)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  387.                 self.model._meta.object_name
```

---

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

I am following exactly the official [documentation](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.1/install.html).

Where should look for the error? Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have django.contrib.sites in installed apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `django.contrib.sites` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and you are not having multiple sites, then you have remove it and do a round of `makemigration` and `migrate`.

In case you have multiple sites, then ref: [Django - Site matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068518/django-site-matching-query-does-not-exist)

Comment: I do have django.contrib.sites in my INSTALLED_APPS. Also, i did makemigrations and migrate. The error is still persisting.

Comment: Did you try removing it?  And doing makemigration and migrate?

Comment: Yes. First, I tried just to makemigrations and migrate. Than I just removed the database and the migrations and made everything again.

Comment: Is you are using Django allauth then use SITE_ID = 1 in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

Adding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068518/django-site-matching-query-does-not-exist). This should work

Enter Django shell

```
$> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site()
>>> site.domain = 'example.com'
>>> site.name = 'example.com'
>>> site.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `django.contrib.sites` in django `INSTALLED_APPS` and also add `SITE_ID=1` in your django setting file.