# Why does removing 'django.contrib.sites' from INSTALLED_APPS fix the 'DoesNotExist at /admin/' error that I suddenly got?

Tags: django, django-admin

Yesterday I set up a new Django app and the admin was still ok when I stopped working. This morning I run the server, and I see this error page:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

I hadn't touched any of the code or made any changes to the database. While looking for an answer, I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736975/django-admin-doesnotexist-at-admin), and indeed, removing `'django.contrib.sites'` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in my `settings.py` file does "solve" the problem, but now I'm wondering *why*. I obviously had that line in `INSTALLED_APPS` yesterday while I was still working, but I'm wondering why it suddenly stopped working today when I hadn't touched any code since then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `Site` object to be present in the `sites` table. For some reason, the `Site` object was not created.

Try this

Log into your django shell

```
$> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site()
>>> site.domain = 'example.com'
>>> site.name = 'example.com'
>>> site.save()
```

OR

```
$> ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> site = Site.objects.create(domain='example.com', name='example.com')
>>> site.save()
```

This should fix your problem.

You could also refer to [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework) about enabling the `Sites` framework:

To enable the sites framework, follow these steps:

- Add 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
- Define a SITE_ID setting:

  SITE_ID = 1
- Run migrate.

> django.contrib.sites registers a `post_migrate` signal handler which creates a default site named `example.com` with the domain `example.com`. This site will also be created after Django creates the test database. To set the correct name and domain for your project, you can use an [initial data fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation. Do you have any idea why it might have disappeared?

Comment: may be you did not have it initially. And after you added sites to installed_apps, you did not migrate.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it... I think I ran `./manage.py flush` which removed the row from the `sites` table.