# Django-registration for 1.6: The requested URL /accounts/login was not found on this server

Tags: django, django-registration

I downloaded the new version of Django-registration which works with Django 1.6:

```
https://github.com/macropin/django-registration#egg=django-registration
```

Installed it, copied registration folder to the project folder, executed syncdb.
In urls.py(project) I added `'url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),'`

settings.py:

```
'INSTALLED_APPS = (..., 'registration',)
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7'
```

When I go to the link `'/localhost/accounts/login/'`, I get `'404 Not Found The requested URL /accounts/login/ was not found on this server'.`
And it's not a message by Django debugger.

In apache accesse log:

```
'::1 - - [13/Oct/2014:21:45:12 +0400] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 213'
```

I read here all related posts on this topic but did not find solutions.

What went wrong?

PS. In apache error log: `'localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name'` But I can go to links `/localhost/some_link_not_accounts/`

Answer (score 0):

I found. There were two reasons:

1. Should be `/localhost/ProjectName/accounts/login/` not `/localhost/accounts/login/`
2. [Django admin DoesNotExist at /admin/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736975/django-admin-doesnotexist-at-admin)