# DoesNotExist at /admin/login/

Tags: django

```
  DoesNotExist at /admin/login/

Site matching query does not exist.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://tehb123.pythonanywhere.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version:     1.9.3
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Site matching query does not exist.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 387
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     3.5.1
Python Path:    

['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/home/tehb123/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/var/www',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/tehb123/mysite']

Server time:    Thu, 13 Oct 2016 05:34:55 +0000
```

- urls

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.contrib.flatpages import views


  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('Mysitez.urls')),
    # url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
  ]

  urlpatterns += [
     url(r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', views.flatpage),
  ]
  ```
- settings

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.templatetags',
    'django.apps',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'Mysitez',
  ]
  ```

Comment: If you are trying to access admin site login page then it is just /admin/ and not /admin/login/

Comment: are you using django-allauth?

Comment: im try - /admin/ , * 
 
are you using django-allauth? - no

Answer (score 4):

SITE_ID=1 in setting and all work, but why? not have idae =(

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736975/django-admin-doesnotexist-at-admin):

"You don't really need the sites framework if you only run one site from the project, so the easiest fix would be to remove the following item from your INSTALLED_APPS and the error should go away:

> 'django.contrib.sites'

"

Answer (score 0):

## The admin site

once you create the project with django version > 1.6 , the admin site will enable django itself. but make sure you have following ["https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/"], once you create project , make `python manage.py migrate` then  create the admin user using (`python manage.py createsuperuser` ). do the run command see the url like ("http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/") you can see the login page

Comment: superuser - create

Comment: migrate - Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: flatpages, admin, sites, sessions, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: check your project settings.py , please add your settings.py file