# How can I fix this Django admin issue? Django admin Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, admin

My admin does not work. I already tried it for a couple of hours.

The migration works:

```
C:\Users\sebas\AI_MachineLearning\Django_Projekt\pythonprojects\cookbook>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, recipes, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

C:\Users\sebas\AI_MachineLearning\Django_Projekt\pythonprojects\cookbook>

The Superuser is created.

Runserver works:
C:\Users\sebas\AI_MachineLearning\Django_Projekt\pythonprojects\cookbook>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 18, 2019 - 22:06:57
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'cookbook.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

If I try the urls `../admin`:

http://dpaste.com/069QF7H

---

**DoesNotExist at /admin/login/**

```
Site matching query does not exist.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version:     2.2.5
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Site matching query does not exist.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\sebas\.conda\envs\pythonDjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 408
Python Executable:  C:\Users\sebas\.conda\envs\pythonDjango\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.7
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\sebas\\AI_MachineLearning\\Django_Projekt\\pythonprojects\\cookbook',
 'C:\\Users\\sebas\\.conda\\envs\\pythonDjango\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\sebas\\.conda\\envs\\pythonDjango\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\sebas\\.conda\\envs\\pythonDjango\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sebas\\.conda\\envs\\pythonDjango',
 'C:\\Users\\sebas\\.conda\\envs\\pythonDjango\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Mi, 18 Sep 2019 21:55:32 +0200
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you add a `path` to your admin site in cookbook\cookbook\urls.py?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_shell',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'recipes'
)

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = (    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls ),
    #urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/shell/', django_admin_shell.urls),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
)

Comment: Hello Jordan, thanks for your answer. Yes I did.

Comment: Looks like your paths are commented. Please add it to your question so we can take a better look at it.

Comment: I have tried several variants and therefore commented out a few! urlpatterns =  (path('admin/', admin.site.urls),)

Comment: Try removing 'django.contrib.sites' if you're not going to use more than 1 site. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737344/8895630) post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed 'django.contrib.sites' and try the commands in the python manage.py shell. It doen't work in my case

Comment: IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: django_site.id

Comment: '--> 383         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    384
    385     def executemany(self, query, param_list):'

Comment: After removing `django.contrib.sites` you don't need to run the other command, that's the alternative in case you **do** need to user more than 1 site. You can't do both solutions. Just try to run your server, without creating a `Site` in the `shell`

Answer (score 0):

Add `SITE_ID = 1` in `settings.py` file.