# DoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: django

DoesNotExist at /admin/

URL matching query does not exist.

I copy code form old study-project and i haven't similar problem in old project.

**settings.py INSTALLED_APPS:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cutter',
]
```

**admin.py:**

```
from .models import URL
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(URL)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('cutter.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

All another functions work.

Comment: Hi! Check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736975/django-admin-doesnotexist-at-admin

Comment: I haven't in Installed apps 'django.contrib.sites'

Comment: "Add django.contrib.sites in django INSTALLED_APPS and also add SITE_ID=1 in your django setting file" try if this works..