# there has been an admin login error in my code

Tags: python, django, django-models

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNe7O.png)

i am not able to see the admin login page
i have made seperate pages one named hello and the other my app home
i am very new to django
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBvdv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muife.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPppx.png)
here are some of the screenshots of my code
to make it seem better

Comment: can you look at this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737344/13861187

Comment: Don't post images of the code. Just post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

remove the following item from your INSTALLED_APPS and the error should go away:

`'django.contrib.sites'`